# Why cant i retreive my BTH coins from my blockchain wallet

Tags: blockchain.info, bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

I logged into my wallet on blockchain.com today. I followed the links through and saw that I had been credited with a equivalent number of bitcoin cash coins that I had been expecting.

I had a few other things to do whilst there so did those first then when I went back to deal with the BTH coins they were no longer showing. what can I do to reclaim my BTH?

btw the other things I did were to move BTC from addresses into my wallet  I also backed up my wallet and recorded a new 12 word phrase but these shouldn't has had any bearing on my entitlement to BTH

Comment: What is BTH?  If you mean Bitcoin Cash, the usual abbreviations is BCH (some people use BCC).

Comment: Welcome to the site! This may be an issue best followed up with the blockchain.com site itself.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by BTH you mean BCH for Bitcoin Cash.

Blockchain.info does not support Bitcoin Cash so you cannot retrieve your Bitcoin Cash as that is an altcoin. However you can take your 12 word seed phrase and use it in a Bitcoin Cash wallet software that supports BIP 39 like Electron Cash to recover your coins.

Comment: hi Andrew @highly thks for thoughts.I wrote to blockchain.info  same day as I posted here but no reply. To clarify, blockchain.info do support BCH and I followed their instructions &found my BCH in my wallet but after I had moved my addresses into the wallet & made a  backup the BCH that I saw earlier had gone.  I was going to try to use the Bitcoin cash wallet site called BTC.com who say I can use a tool they have devised to recover my BCH from blockchain.info into my BTC.com wallet but to do this I have to insert my seed phrase and don't know if it is wise/safe to do this.

Comment: The only way for you to access your Bitcoin Cash is to enter you seed phrase into some other wallet software. That seed phrase is what allows the software to generate your private keys so that you can access your BCH. However that same seed phrase also allows them to generate the private keys for your Bitcoin, so you should move your Bitcoin to a different wallet entirely (not address, wallet) before continuing.